# Unable to locate package pi-bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, ros

I want use a game controller to control my ros car on raspberrypi with bluetooth. But I can not install `pi-bluetooth` and `blue-firmware.`

First I has updated mirror address on ubuntu18.04 and typed following command. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade,` nothing error.

But when I run this command `sudo apt-get install pi-bluetooth` , give me a error.

`unable to locate package pi-bluetooth`, same operation to intall geographic_msgs,but the error is  `unable to locate package ros-melodic-geographic_msgs`.
I want know if my steps is something wrong. It is exist that raspberrypi don't support ubuntu18.04? Okay I try to replace the mirror address, but it don't work.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your question over at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) since it is not programming related